# Gnuplot plot data with text column as X axis

Tags: gnuplot

I have a text file as follows:

```
ls 10
cd 5
cut 12
awk 7
...
```

I would like to plot it using gnuplot with the text column as the X axis:

```
plot 'data.txt' u 1:2
```

But I get this error:

```
         warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
                         ^
         x range is invalid
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$data << EOD
ls 10
cd 5
cut 12
awk 7
EOD

# this is all just plot layout stuff; customize to taste
unset border
set tics scale 0
set xzeroaxis
set title "x coord = line number"

# use line number for x coordinate, column 1 for tic label
plot $data using 0:2:xticlabel(1) with impulse
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check `help xticlabels`.
And try this:

```
reset session

$Data <<EOD
ls 10
cd 5
cut 12
awk 7
...  9
EOD

set boxwidth 0.7
set style fill solid 1.0
set yrange[0:]

plot $Data u 2:xtic(1) w boxes
```